# Laravel Echo not using Auth Headers

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-echo

I update the header like this:

```
window.setAuthToken = (token) => {
    window.Echo.options.auth.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
}
```

The token is set in the Laravel Echo Headers, as seen here:
[image: Console result]

But it is **not used**, as seen here:
[image: Headers]

> Why is Laravel Echo not using Auth Headers?

**Edit:**
I also tried dynamically update the endpoint like `window.Echo.connector.options.authEndpoint = '';`, and it is set in the options but not used by the request.

This is how I connect to the channel.

```
Echo.private('app.User.' + data.user_id)
    .notification((notification) => {
        dispatch('handle', notification);
    });
```

Comment: Please post the code where you're firing the request

Comment: I edited my question with the code. Do you need more than that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the way to do it was pretty close to what I was trying. [Solution was found here.](https://github.com/laravel/echo/issues/26#issuecomment-248178873)

```
Echo.connector.pusher.config.auth.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer token';
```

Comment: this gives `[Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "isAuthenticated": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'pusher' of undefined"`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
window.Echo.connector.options.auth.headers.Authorization = "Bearer token";
```

"laravel-echo": "^1.15.3",