# Laravel Echo + VueJS broadcast/auth problem

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, pusher, pusher-js

I'm using Laravel Echo and pusher as my server. It is working already on public channels.

Here is the photo of my laravel echo listener [image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c88R.png)

Now my problem is when I use PrivateChannel and when I listen in the private channel this error pops out:

POST http://localhost:3000/broadcasting/auth 500 (Internal Server Error)

Inside the error in the console/network tab it says Route [login] not defined.

Here is an image inside the console/network https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnAGp.png

Things I have done:

> -Uncommented App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class in config/app.php
>
> -Added Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:api']]); in BroadcastServiceProvider.php
>
> -Used Echo.private('channel-name') instead of Echo.channel('channel-name') for listening to private channels
>
> -Added authEndpoint : 'http://localhost:3000/broadcasting/auth' to bootstrap.js(This is where my Echo options are)
>
> -Added a channel(probably the private channel) in my channels.php ([here is a photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tejVg.png))
>
> -Added csrf token meta tag in my main blade

In the pusher server it recieves the event when it is fired, here is a
[picture of the event successfully fired.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvifG.png)

So the problem is when I listen to a private channel the error pops out but everything is okay when listening to a public channel, And I am not so sure how to assess with this problem.

Comment: can you please show your routes/channels.php file and also did you add the CSRF Token meta tag field in your base layout page?

Comment: @Md.MirajKhan please check photo in post

Comment: Are you logged in using API Auth?

Comment: @Md.MirajKhan I use Laravel Passport for my API authentication which uses the auth api middleware

Comment: so then you have to pass your api_toke with the pusher route.

Comment: @Md.MirajKhan where and what are you pointing exactly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass the auth header with the pusher request like below.

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'APP_KEY',
    authEndpoint: '/broadcasting/auth'
    auth: {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer your_api_Toke',
            'X-CSRF-Token': "CSRF_TOKEN"
         }
      }
    });
```

For more details:

https://github.com/laravel/echo/issues/26
[Laravel Echo not using Auth Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47723149/laravel-echo-not-using-auth-headers)

Comment: To add to the answer, if using Laravel API on the backend with Vue on the front end you probably do not want to be using CSRF_TOKEN at all.  So remove that from the header on the front end and on laravel go to app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php and add 'broadcasting/auth' to $except[].  Can also do that for testing until you get everything else working.